# Creating a fanout service using Websocket connection

Tags: websocket, architecture, system-design

im trying to build an application that serves real time data to the end users. i was thinking of using a websocket connection since the data is alot (10 events/sec). the trouble is this, the data is coming from a websocket connection from a third party.
I am limited to only 1 websocket connection and in future i can ask for more but only a couple.

What im thinking is designing a websocket fanout service that works somewhat like this.
[image]
Proposed design.
I'm confused about the reliability of such design and how i can scale it efficiently.
This is an open ended question since Im really ironing out the design details but i would love any experienced input here.

PS: Im either going to use Node.js or Spring boot in the backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a few questions:

- How are the end users accessing this data from the intermediary? is it through HTTP, Web Sockets, Polling, or PubSub?
- How is the data going to be stored in the intermediate state (received from the socket but not accessed by the end users)?

Since this resembles a system that ingests realtime market data, I will suggest a few things:

- implement a POC of this system and check the time delta between when the event originally occurred and when it was received by the end users.
- Use a high-compression packet format for sending data to clients (protobuf) since JSON is slow in serialization / de-serialization and also bulky
- Assess the amount of data that needs to be processed, and make sure that the intermediary server has good computing power and enough memory to provide the necessary throughput/performance along with being able to store data in memory

Comment: To the answer the questions:
I'm using a mix of HTTP (config and stored data) & websocket for real time.
Im currently using DynamoDB but setting up stuff so i can move on to elastic search later on. 
i havent used Server side events but they seem like a better option in this case, also dynamoDB is like my go to db for now in key-value pairs so that's what i started with

The suggestions are really helpful and i am currently working on a few of them Thanks.